# I have p element inside a div both have equal height 50px. Why is p shifted downwards?

Tags: html, css

[image: This is the new result after Amit's answer][image]Both p and div and have no margins or padding. As shown

https://jsfiddle.net/4vqgj0qe/3/

Here i have two buttons named 'Aug,' & '2017' in a

element of id #semiScreen, which is inside a  element of id #button-bar with other buttons. While the other buttons are in place. The buttons inside p is shifted a little downwards(seems that whole p is shifted downwards) as can be seen in the Sep button in the picture given. Why are they shifted downwards and How to show them like other buttons?

html:

```
    <body>
       <p id="demo"></p>
       <input type="text" id="dateInput" name="dateInput">
       <button>▼</button>
       <div id="calender" style="display: block;">
<div class="button-bar">
  <button>《</button>
  <button>&lt;</button>
  <p id="semiScreen">
    <button>Aug,</button>
    <button>2017</button>
  </p>
  <button>&gt;</button>
  <button>》</button>
</div>
<table id="calTable">
  <tr>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>M</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>T</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>S</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
   * {
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
   }

   table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
      font-size: 20px;
   }

   table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }

  td {
      padding: 4px 10px;
      text-align: center;
  }

  td:hover {
      color: white;
      background-color: #888;
  }

  body {
      font-family: Arial;
  }

  #calender {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      display: none;
  }

  #calender table {
      width: 287px;
  }

  div.button-bar {
      height: 50px;
      /*line-height: 100%;*/
       width: 287px;
  }

  #semiScreen {
      padding: 0px;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 127px;
      margin: 0px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }

  #calender div.button-bar button {
      background: white;
      height: 100%;
      border: none;
      margin: 0px;
      width: 35px;
      outline: none;
  }

  #calender div.button-bar button:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #888;
  }

   #calender div.button-bar #semiScreen button {
     width: auto;
   }
```

Comment: I'm sure it's because of weird nature of `>>`, because `>` it's a symbol placed by code, while `>>` and `<<` are placed like one symbol that can have different font sizes which can lead these strange shifts to bottom

Comment: Please proofread your posts, and read the documentation about formatting. To include a tag such as `<p>` in your post, you need to enclose it in backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
  vertical-align: middle;
```

from `#semiScreen` in css

The calendar box small shift downwards in css is due to text characters in use to render arrows.

This works for me on a standalone html page.

```
<div class="button-bar">
      <button>&#171;</button>
      <button>&lt;</button>
      <p id="semiScreen">
        <button>Aug,</button>
        <button>2017</button>
      </p>
      <button>&gt;</button>
      <button>&#187;</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Removing that made it equivalent to other buttons, but they all are a little downward. Can you help a little more. I am adding the new result as image.

Comment: Sergey Gultyaev is also right. The weird nature of arrow is causing small displacement in screen pixels. I have pasted the alternative in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in this way. I replaced your symbols of double arrows which were placed in unknown way, to codes of these arrows according to this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_math.asp)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 20px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

td {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #888;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

#calender {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

#calender table {
  width: 287px;
}

div.button-bar {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 100%;
  width: 287px;
}

#semiScreen {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 127px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#calender div.button-bar button {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 35px;
  outline: none;
}

#calender div.button-bar button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #888;
}

#calender div.button-bar #semiScreen button {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <input type="text" id="dateInput" name="dateInput">
  <button>▼</button>
  <div id="calender" style="display: block;">
    <div class="button-bar">
      <button>&#x226A;</button>
      <button>&lt;</button>
      <p id="semiScreen">
        <button>Aug,</button>
        <button>2017</button>
      </p>
      <button>&gt;</button>
      <button>&#x226B;</button>
    </div>
    <table id="calTable">
      <tr>
        <th>S</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>S</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>31</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the double arrows.